# Vbulletin Custom BBcode, Flowplayer and RTMP

Tags: rtmp, flowplayer, vbulletin

I'm trying to embed flowplayer in  my clients vbulletin forum and have succeeded with basic videos in the s3 bucket but am having trouble trying to implement rtmp. I've set up the distribution ok and can stream to a plain html page outside of vbulletin but am hitting a wall trying to write a custom bbcode to embed in posts.

My code for basic embed looks like this in my cusotom bbcode...

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="624" height="352" data="http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/forums /flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">  
<param name="movie" value="http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/forums/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf" />  
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />  
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /> 
<param name="quality" value="autohigh" />  
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"autoPlay":false,"accelerated":true,"url":"{param}"}}' />  
</object>
```

And my working rmtp streaming looks like this...

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Streaming Video with Flowplayer
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>HSL501 Observation Video</H1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/forums/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.11.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
<div id="rtmpPlayer" style="display:block;width:1000px;height:500px;"></div>
<script language="javascript">
// our custom configuration is given in third argument
flowplayer("rtmpPlayer", "http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/forums/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf",{
plugins: {
  rtmp: {
    url: 'http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/forums/flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.11.swf',
    netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://XXXX.cloudfront.net/cfx/st'
  }
},
clip: {
  url: 'mp4:entries%207.mp4'',
  provider: 'rtmp'
}
});
</script>
</div>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out and hopefully this will help somebody else and save them having to search for hours like I did.

```
<object width="656" height="420" data="http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/forums/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/forums/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"url":"mp4:{param}","bufferLength":1,"provider":"dtfl"},"plugins":{"dtfl":{"url":"http://www.MY_DOMAIN.com/forums/flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.11.swf","netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://XXXXX.cloudfront.net/cfx/st"},"controls":{"backgroundGradient":[0.1,0.3,0,0,0],"bufferGradient":"none","sliderColor":"#272727","backgroundColor":"#000","sliderGradient":"small","buttonOverColor":"#272727","borderRadius":"0px","buttonColor":"#565656","timeColor":"#CCCCCC","progressColor":"#565656","durationColor":"#ffffff","bufferColor":"#CCCCCC","progressGradient":"medium","opacity":1}}}' />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Steve, in Clip --> url , you are giving My_Domain, whereas it should be URI of your file present in S3. Let me know exactly what is happening when you load the page and play video, as we also faced issues in making it work , but finally did it after few fixes.

Comment: Hi - I put MY_DOMAIN by accident when posting here. The actualy working html code has 'mp4:entries%207.mp4' (the name of the file). The s3 version is working fine. It's the streaming version I can't figure out the bbcode for. Have a working rmtp using the cloudfront distro. Now I just need to figure out the bbcode.